# Rails - calling an instance variable from anywhere in the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I am fairly new to Rails, so apologies if it's not an 'instance variable' I am talking about!

I am using Devise for authentication, so can use things like current_user throughout the app. The app I am building has a User model, but also a Keyholder model (who is a sort of moderator for that user), and a Guest (who has read-only access to some things for that user).

What I want to know is - can I set it up so that I can use e.g. access_user when logged in as the keyholder to access the same object as current_user - and if so, where do I put the code in my app? It's quickly becoming very verbose and un-Rails-like having to repeat myself otherwise.

What I am trying to achieve is being able to use 'access_user' instead of current_user, so that regardless of whether it is the user, keyholder or guest logged in, it will use the user object.

For example:

```
def access_user
  if user_signed_in?
    access_user = current_user
  end
  if keyholder_signed_in?
    access_user = current_keyholder.user
  end
  if guest_signed_in?
    access_user = current_guest.user
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: where are you defining this?

Comment: I want to be able to use it throughout the app, so don't know where to define it - the code above is an example of what I am trying to achieve - being able to use access_user anywhere in the app in much the same way as I can currently use current_user because of Devise.

Comment: you could define it in the application_controller.rb

Comment: I tried that - when I am using e.g. users/<%= access_user.id %>/events it says undefined local variable or method `access_user'.

Comment: IF you need it in the view, you could define it in the application_helper

Comment: If I do that, I get the error "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id" - is this because it is calling the helper before current_user etc has been defined? If so, how do I get this code to set the access_user object *after* current_user etc has been set?

Comment: you could extend devise helper. I am afraid that's about my knowledge of ruby for now

Comment: Thanks for your help - do you know how I would extend the helper so that the one I create inherits from the Devise helpers?

Comment: you just need to create a file called devise_helper.rb in the same place as action_helper.rb I am not sure of the scope of devise_helper. I'll look this up when I get home and try to find a real solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class level instance variables](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) could also help you.

```
def access_user
  if user_signed_in?
    @access_user = current_user
  end
  if keyholder_signed_in?
    @access_user = current_keyholder.user
  end
  if guest_signed_in?
    @access_user = current_guest.user
  end
end
```

Comment: This wasn't working, but I added before_filter :access_user to the top of the applications controller as well as a method similar to this and now it works, thanks. There isn't any security reason that I can't use this with a before_filter is there?

Comment: Umm.. access_user should be set before every method? Then before_filter does make sense. I think, there is no need to have an instance variable in your case. Am gonna edit my answer to make it better.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work without the before filter - it was coming up with errors when I tried to use any Devise helpers e.g. current_user, saying they were nil. It works with the before_filter in place, don't understand why though.

Comment: Without the before_filter, where were you calling the access_user method?

Comment: It's in the application controller, and I wanted it to be available across all controllers/views, much the same way as current_user is.

Comment: Strangely, that gives me a "undefined local variable or method `access_user'" error, if I use it the way you have suggested. No idea why :S

Comment: Oh. I see. You have defined access_user in application_controller I believe.

Comment: Oops. Did you try @access_user ?

Comment: Yep - that's what's working for me - but I'm having to call it as @access_user, as well as using the before_filter. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just set this method in ApplicationController, and expose it to a helper method.

```
class ApplicationController
  helper_method :access_user

  def access_user
    #blah blah
  end
end
```

When method in ApplicationController, it's available to all controllers.

When you use `helper_method`, it is exposed as helper method to be used in View. More about `helper_method`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: That is giving me the 'called id for nil' error. I am defining the method exactly as in the question, plus using the helper_method - any ideas why? I am calling it in a view e.g. <%= access_user.id %>. Could it be because the current_user object hasn't been created before this code is running? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your judgement should be right. My answer only answers the question in title but guest user implementation is quite complex. For the later question, yes, if you don't have method to create guest user for visitor, current_user is nil. This is nothing about where you put the method.

Comment: I would suggest you to implement guest user feature at the last. It's only a supplement and should not take too much effort at beginning. My suggestion is to stick to `current_user` all the time instead of other 'access_user' method. Later you can overwrite this method to add guest functionality.

Comment: current_user should be being defined by Devise somewhere - so I need to know where to put my method so that it inherits from Devise, instead of being run before. I have got everything built & working with current_user, but now that I need to add guest functionality, I need to get this way round working instead.

Comment: In application controller as well `def current_user; super || create_guest_user; end`